# Do I need an ESTA for Austria as a US citizen?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, austria

I am American. My Italian girlfriend who lives in Vienna says that I may have to apply for an ESTA visa to visit her. Is this correct? The last time I went to Europe (not Austria) I did not have to fill out a visa...

Comment: As an American, you need an *ETA* (like an ESTA) for *Australia*, but hopefully your girlfriend didn't confuse Austria and Australia when living there!

Comment: haha, thanks for the tip. i'll double check that before i embark..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is indeed **no**; no visa or ESTA of any kind needed for a visit of 90 days or less.

Here's what the **[US State Department (Bureau of Consular Affairs)](http://travel.state.gov/travel/cis_pa_tw/cis/cis_965.html)** has  to say:

> ENTRY / EXIT REQUIREMENTS FOR U.S. CITIZENS:
>    Austria is a party to the
>   Schengen Agreement. As such, **U.S. citizens may enter Austria for up to
>   90 days in any 180-day period for tourist or business purposes without
>   a visa**. The passport used should be valid at least for the period of
>   the intended stay (usually the date of the return flight).
>
> Anyone intending to stay longer than 90 days must obtain the
>   appropriate visa issued by the Austrian Embassy in the United States.
>   Specifically students attending a college/university in Austria should
>   consult with the Austrian Embassy/Consulate before coming to Austria.
>   Information for students is available from the Austrian agency for
>   international mobility and cooperation in education, science and
>   research (OeAD).

Also, technically one can only need an [**ESTA**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_System_for_Travel_Authorization) for the United States, as it's related to the [US visa waiver program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Waiver_Program). Similar systems in other counties are called something else than "ESTA".

Comment: I^m not so sure if the US bureau of consular affairs is more reliable as its Austrian counterpart. Normally, you should check visa requirements, in the destination country.

Comment: I was merely referring to the [wrong source](http://www.bmeia.gv.at/fileadmin/user_upload/bmeia/media/5-Buergerservice_Zentrale/ReiseGrenzverkehr/Einreisevoraussetzungen_fuer_OEsterreichische_Staatsbuerger.pdf) you initially used. (Will edit my answer.)

Comment: In any case, I think Americans might find it reassuring to read the (same) information in English from US authorities.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [page](http://www.bmeia.gv.at/aussenministerium/buergerservice/pass-und-visum.html) of the Austrian foreign affairs office. As a US citizen, you don't need a visa.

There is also a [list of all countries](http://www.bmeia.gv.at/fileadmin/user_upload/bmeia/media/5-Buergerservice_Zentrale/ReiseGrenzverkehr/Einreisevoraussetzungen_nach_OEsterreich.pdf) and their entry regulations. Unfortunately it is only available in German.

Comment: Umm, but the source you give says "[**Teilweise visafrei**; vor der Einreise allerdings ist eine elektronische Registrierung erforderlich.](http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Teilweise%20visafrei%3B%20vor%20der%20Einreise%20allerdings%20ist%20eine%20elektronische%20Registrierung%20erforderlich.%0AInformationen%20entnehmen%20Sie%20bitte%20der%20L%C3%A4nderinfo%20bzw.%20der%20Homepage%20der%20Botschaft%20des%20betroffenen%20Staates)" which sounds "ESTA like" to me!

Comment: where did you find that? I can't see it.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. The source (the PDF) you link to is wrong; it's "Entry requirements for *Austrian citizens*" for different countries.

Comment: Ah I see, I copied the wrong link. I have correct that.