# Do I need to show amount of money at airport in France?

Tags: france, money

I want to travel to France for 2 weeks vacation as a tourist.  But since my trip is a sudden one, I am planning to stay in a hotel for a few days then will be meeting a few friends there.  Will they ask me a full paid 2 weeks booking confirmation? Is 1500 euro enough to show at the airport?

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/33864/documents-necessary-and-recommended-for-first-time-travel-to-eu-for-us-citizen

Answer (score 1):

1. From my personal experience, the border guards in the EU region rarely ask for documents other than passport, visa and sometimes insurance. Of course, that also depends on your nationality and the place of origin of your journey. If you are concerned about them asking for confirmed accommodation, simply book a no-deposit, free cancellation hotel on booking.com and cancel it after printing the confirmation page. That should be fine.
2. They don't ask you to show money either. Anyway 1500 Euros is good enough to cover you for two weeks, given that you already have confirmed accommodation.

Comment: Hi..thanks for the infos. Very useful but I come from The Seychelles.  We do not need visa cause we had been exempt from it.

Comment: Will it be okay to mention that I will be meeting up with my English boyfriend, cause he will be the one waiting for me at the airport.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to enter France with 1500€ in cash? No problem: you only have to declare the money when it is above 10000€.

So you don’t have to declare it.

> Les sommes (espèces ou chèques), titres (actions, obligations, etc.)
>   ou valeurs d’un montant égal ou supérieur à 10.000 euros (ou son
>   équivalent en devises), transportés par une personne physique, doivent
>   être déclarés à l'administration des douanes qui effectue des
>   contrôles en ce domaine, afin de lutter contre le blanchiment des
>   capitaux provenant de trafics illicites, notamment des stupéfiants.

Source: [Obligation déclarative des sommes, titres et valeurs](http://www.douane.gouv.fr/articles/a10796-obligation-declarative-des-sommes-titres-et-valeurs)

There is also no specify amount of money that you must have: it must only be "enough". The law is explicitly vague about this:

> Tous les ressortissants étrangers qui souhaitent venir en France
>   doivent être en mesure de présenter à la frontière les justificatifs
>   réglementaires relatifs à l'objet du séjour, aux moyens d'existence et
>   aux conditions d'hébergement.

Your return ticket and hotel reservation/friend’s address is plenty enough if you are a "normal" tourist (that is, not a punk beatnik with a beach towel for only baggage :).

Comment: I think you've answered a different point - the OP isn't worried about it from the customs point of view, they're worried they might have to show proof of funds to the immigration officer deciding about letting them in or not

Comment: Oh, you might be right. I am adding the info, then.

Comment: @DamienClauzel That's actually incorrect, the law is much more detailed than that.